# Search record accross multiple MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop

I have a question regarding searching records across multiple MySQL tables.
In my case I have 400 MySQL tables which are the same as below (ex: Table1,Table2,Table3...Table400) and each table contains 1 million rows.

enter image description here
[image]

Is there any easy method to search across all the tables at once (using Field1 it is not a key in addition duplicates available in that filed) using SQL command line or Hadoop?

Thanks